# Is there a way to show a string between a tablix and the end of the page?

Tags: report, reporting, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I need to show a textbox with a static content after a tablix in order to cover the white space of the page, if there is.

I tried with a textbox (with the same height of the page) below the tablix but it appears only on the first page and not in all pages of the report. Also by setting the background of the tablix to white, the textbox is seen the same.

I tried adding a row at the bottom of the tablix but I can't find an appropriate visibility expression

Someone ran into the same issue?

Comment: May I ask what's your status? Did you find any solutions? Like put the textbox in the footer or use other reporting solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It's possible with Crystal Report for Visual Studio. You can try this out since it's free, but you would have to change the report generation code and make a new report template in Crystal Report.